# Making a custom Calendar month view...How to align days properly?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am creating my own calendar and bumped into a bit of an issue... Right now I am using `Date.today.beginning_of_month` to get the current month. My controller is set up like so...

```
#Controller
  def calendar
     @day_of_month = current_month    
  end

  def current_month
    date = Date.today.beginning_of_month
    return (date..date + 31.days).to_a
  end
```

In my view I have the following....

```
<% @days_of_month.each_slice(7) do |slice| %>
  <div class="week_row_in_month">
    <% slice.each do |day| %>
      <div class="month_day" id="<%= day %>">
        <div class="header">
          <%= day.strftime("%A") %>
        </div>
      </div>
    <% end %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The issue is my "calendar" starts on the first day of the month (I understand why... because of the `beginning_of_month` method)... But if April 1st fell on a Wednesday... how would I get it aligned so it fell on a Wednesday div and not aligned like it was on a Sunday div?

I hope that makes sense. If there is any confusing let me know and I will edit to clarify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get your calendar to start at the beginning of the week in the way you described, you can do something like this:

```
# Controller

def calendar
   @days_of_month = current_month    
end

def current_month
  date = Date.today.beginning_of_month
  start_date = date - date.wday
  end_date = date.end_of_month + (6 - date.end_of_month.wday)
  return (start_date..end_date).to_a
end
```

Since the `Date#wday` method returns the day of the week as a number (0-6, Sunday is zero), you can use it to quickly find the starting day of the week. More info on this method can be found here: http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.1/libdoc/date/rdoc/Date.html#method-i-wday

Comment: Also I think you need to put the end_date -->  end_date = date.end_of_month + (6-date.end_of_month.wday) to make the perfect rectangle view